# Android LeftNavBar OptionsMenu Doesn't Work on Device

Tags: android, google-tv

I downloaded the GoogleTV LeftNavBar library and demo:
http://code.google.com/p/googletv-android-samples/

But I'm seeing odd behavior. When i build and run the demo app on my Galaxy Tab 10.1 (Android 3.1), the options menu never shows (even after I toggle the "Options Menu With/Without" button). I can run it on the simulator and it shows up as an old-style options menu (coming up from the bottom), but I'm concerned since it doesn't work on my tablet. it leaves me wondering if it will work on a Google TV.

If anyone has some experience with this sample and could lend an explanation, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This will work if you use the Google TV emulator. http://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_setup_android.html